# What is the relationship or difference between MLE and EM algorithm?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, statistical-mechanics, data-mining

I am trying to study EM algorithm and Maximum Likelihood Estimation. Somehow, they both sound the same to me but can't really say the difference. Maybe I don't really understand any of them. I have just started.

Can somebody tell me what they do and the relationship or difference between them?

Comment: MLE gives you the objective to maximize. EM is one method for finding this maximum. In other words, EM finds (or attempts to find) the MLE iteratively. There are other methods, e.g. pick any optimization method.

Comment: I believe that's very broad question. One possible difference: if you want to estimate parameters $\alpha_i$, $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$ of Gaussian mixture $\sum_i \alpha_i N(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$, you cannot use MLE and you must use EM-algorithm instead and find parameters iteratively. On the other hand, when $\alpha_i$'s are known, you can use MLE. It is like directly solving an equation if possible (MLE), or using some iterative numeric method otherwise.

Comment: When can I use em and when I cannot use it? How can I distinguish?

Comment: EM is computationally more  expensive, so use MLE if possible. Try to use MLE In my upper example when $\alpha_i$'s are unknown (really - try it, that helped me, when I came across EM algorithm). Then,  you will understand in which cases you cannot use MLE. (When some of your parameters (in our case $\alpha_i$'s) are unobservable.)

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REypj2sy_5U) video and the next one in the playlist helped me for start. Then, I was able to understand Wikipedia's article and some others.

Comment: Antoine, what did you mean by $\alpha$. And it sounds like EM and MLE are both ways of finding probabilities, am I correct? If so, EM uses Expectation and Maximization stages and what does MLE use? And it is another curiosity that if I can use EM or MLE for regression analysis to find the parameters?

Comment: @user122358 Assume you have three types $Y_i$ of people: children, grown up men and grown up women and you measure their height $X$. Suppose it's distribution is given as $X\mid Y_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$. $\alpha_i$ is probability that height $X$ belongs to a person of type $Y_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding

**EM**

Assumption: The given data is coming/originated from multiple classes/distribution

Input: Data points

Output: Each data point classified to a distribution and the parameters of the distribution.

**MLE**

Assumption: The distribution from which the data points originate

Input: Data points

Output: Parameters of the distribution which maximizes the probability that the data points have originated from that particular distribution.

If this is correct, then EM might be doing MLE as an intermediate step.

Please correct me if I am wrong.